# How to make circular Legend in corePlote?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I searched this question but did not get appropriate answer.

I'm using CorePlote for graphs and chart in my application.
i tried to customize Legend of Pie Chart to circular but i did not find any method or property for that.

Does any one has any idea about it?

Comment: did you checked this chttps://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=90

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cornerRadius property of radius.
Try following code i hope i will help.

```
theLegend.cornerRadius = [theLegend.bounds.size.width/2];
```

Here `theLegend` is object of `CPTLegend`.

Comment: This didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This approach helped me to make circular legend items:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
theLegend.swatchSize = size
theLegend.swatchCornerRadius = size.height
```